# automate click till the end of carousel using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jcarousel

I want to click on next arrow of a carousel till the end of loop. now how do i click constantly on the next arrow using selenium webdriver ??
I did for-loop in the click but its not working.
This is the basic code for the element and click.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hp_category_tab_electronics_0-content']/div[1]/div/div/a[2]"));
element.click();
```

so in short i want to click on next arrow button for like 5 times before the end of products is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hp_category_tab_electronics_0-content']/div[1]/div/div/a[2]"));
element.click();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++);{
        Thread.sleep(500);
        element.click();
    }
```

I found the code actually i was not using `thread.sleep();` before.

Comment: A better solution would be to use WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath("xpath"))));  instead of Thread.sleep(500);